# To what extent is xenophobia not selective?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I read in the The Economist [that](https://www.economist.com/europe/2018/05/03/anti-semitism-in-europe-may-not-in-fact-be-rising)

> in most countries, anti-Semitism rises or falls in concert with nationalism and identity politics. David Feldman of the Pears Institute notes the importance of “competitive victimhood”, in which claims of oppression by Jews, Muslims and other groups step on each others’ toes. Dariusz Stola, head of the Polin Museum of Polish Jewish History, says the same is true in Poland, where the national story is one of victimisation by Germany and Russia. It is more accurate, he thinks, to see anti-Semitism as part of a general wave of chauvinist sentiment since the migrant crisis of 2015; levels of hostility to Muslims, gays and Roma have risen too. Says Mr Stola: “Xenophobia is not selective.”

Since most observational studies on this are going to have trouble with confounders, are there any controlled experiments of inducing some level of xenophobia and measuring its "halo effect" against out-groups not specifically targeted (by the experimental message)?

Comment: This seems more like a Skeptics kind of question, I don't really see it framed in anything related to psychology or neuroscience. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: @BryanKrause; I've already clarified that I'm looking for controlled "laboratory" experiments, as typically done in psychology studies.

Comment: Try to change the label to social psychology and prejudices. it's possible the control in a sense methodology but the causal control of xenophobia by researchers is not possible, in this way there is no "controlled laboratory experiments". On the other hand it is not a "halo effect" but influence.